# solicion sobre :java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. con glassfish

Tags: java, base-de-datos, glassfish, tls

El error que nos muestra en el glassfish al momento de montar una aplicativo los sale este error 
**Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: El controlador no pudo establecer una conexión segura con SQL Server con el cifrado de Capa de sockets seguros (SSL)**
podemos solucionarlo de la siguiente maneta
nos vamos al servidos de fedora 30 con nucleo 5.0 ingresamos  **cd /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/** y  ingresamos **vi java.config** nos muestra

```
jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=1023
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DH keySize < 1023, SSLv2, SSLv3, DHE_DSS, RSA_EXPORT, DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, DH_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon, ECDH_anon, DH_RSA, DH_DSS, ECDH, 3DES_EDE_CBC, DES_CBC, RC4_40, RC4_128, DES40_CBC, RC2, HmacMD5
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms=
```

solo hacemos un cambio 
que muestre lo siguiente

```
jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=1023
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,Rc4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD2,MD5,RSA keySize < 1023, SSLv3, DHE_DSS, RSA_EXPORT, DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, DH_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon, ECDH_anon, DH_RSA, DH_DSS, ECDH, 3DES_EDE_CBC, DES_CBC, RC4_40, RC4_128, DES40_CBC, RC2, HmacMD5
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms=
```

Comment: Hola. No es claro si tienes un problema, estás compartiendo una solución o cuál es el objetivo del post. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento del sitioo y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola alex, por favor realiza el [tour] del sitio para que conozcas su funcionamiento. Modifica tu pregunta en base a el documento [ask], agrega lo que has tratado o investigado, con esto tendrás mejores respuestas, saludos.